# NLog How to create individual log files for every child class?

Tags: c#, nlog

I use NLog and c#.

I have one ClassBase and two child classes ClassSon, ClassDaughter.

I have a main-application that instantiates in parallel one instance of ClassSon and one instance of ClassDaughter.

I want that the instance of ClassSon logs to the file "ClassSonLog.log" and that of ClassDaughter to the file "ClassDaughter.log".

How can I get each class instance log into its own log file? Do I need two loggers or two FileTargets...?

Comment: Use NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` inside ClassSon and ClassDaughter. Then include `${logger}` in the File-Target-FileName-Layout.

Comment: THank you I also found out that the parameter 'loggerNamePatern' in the AddRule method is responsible for splitting the log stream into different streams:

Comment: @RolfKristensen That should be an answer :)

Comment: Tank you, I also found out that the LoggerNamePattern parameter in the AddRule() method is responsible for spliting the log stream into separate files depending on the class instance:
If I have FileTarget logfileTarget1 = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("NLogExample.Model.ClassSon") { FileName = "NLogExample.Model.ClassSon.log" };
 Tnen I set the pattern to "NLogExample.Model.ClassDaughter" in: config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logfileTarget1, "NLogExample.Model.ClassSon"); I do the same for the ClassDaughter class and it works fine then

Comment: But what if I want to write logs also in the parent class ClassBasic so that depending on the child instance the logs of ClassBasic are written either in ClassSon.log or ClassDaughter.log respectively? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-create-Logger-for-sub-classes

Comment: Thanks again, this link is the solution for the parent class!!

Comment: @RolfKristensen I also want that the main program logger also writes into "ClassSon.log" or "ClassDaughter.log" depending on that which sub class has been instantiated. I still cannot figure this out.. Any idea?

Comment: Can you share the code of all three classes and main class along with the logging code?

Comment: @anarchipur The main-program can just use the Logger-property on the instantiated sub-class.